# [ubuntu19.10]cant boot into unless using sudo mount -o remount,rw /

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, raspberrypi

I was trying to set some mount for SFTP, in the process.

I think I messed up the fstab accidentally.

Now on reboot, it boots into recovery, and using

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

can let me boot into the desktop.

I undo the edits for my mounts but unfortunately, I don't have backup of fstab
tried different fstab

e.g.: change to UUID, different directories etc., still no clue

What could be the problem? pls help...

My fstab:

```
LABEL=system-boot /boot vfat defaults 0 1
LABEL=ssd /media/ubuntu/ssd auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Screenshot running `fsck` on reboot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1

adding something like this solved the issue